# How to make this image responsive?

Tags: html, css

I want to make this html code in responsive for phone / tablet (is gametracker server).

```
<a href="http://www.gametracker.com/server_info/93.119.24.6:9075/" target="_blank">
<img src="http://cache.gametracker.com/server_info/93.119.24.6:9075/b_350_20_000000_000000_CE0808_000000.png" border="0" width="350" height="20" alt=""/></a>
</center>
<a <a href="http://www.gametracker.com/server_info/93.119.27.78:27015/" target="_blank">
<img src="http://cache.gametracker.com/server_info/93.119.27.78:27015/b_350_20_000000_000000_DA1111_000000.png" border="0" width="350" height="20" alt=""/></a>
```

Look I do not like:

[image]

Comment: take a look at bootstrap to make all the website responsive

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

Comment: All is receptive except image server which
destroy tabel .. solution for me is media queris but I do not know how to write that codes in css , please make for me code in css..

Comment: import bootstrap.css , bootstrap.js and use it 
`<img class="img-responsive"...>`

Comment: share the code url

Comment: Note that questions asking readers to "edit the code" (i.e. do your work for you) are not well received here. For any question, please expect that you are going to do the work yourself.

Comment: I succeeded :) thank anyway
..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link bootstrap by adding these lines into your HTML

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And use the below code for responsive img

```
<img class="img-responsive" style="margin:auto; padding:20px;" src="image_url" alt="Alternate Text" width="image_width" height="image_height">
```

Comment: how to use boostrap ?  please give me all step , i`m beginner

Comment: thanks , I solved but files bootstrap not affect loading the page ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap front-end framework

```
<img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
```

or you can define a class by yourself

```
.responsive-img {
    max-width: 100%; 
    display:block; 
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: please give me all step , i`m beginner , how to use bootstrap ?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started ! you can download source code or you can also use bootstrap CDN links !